# Sql query for selected max data group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query
I have this data in table

```
id         id_game           score       level
1            2                1232        2
2            2                1234        2
3            2                234         3
```

I need to get data group by level but with the big score in the same moment
My sql :

```
select * from table where id_game = 2 
GROUP BY level 
ORDER BY level asc
```

This query return the id's : 1 and 3. I need 2 and 3 beceause score 1234 > 1232. Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you please share the result you're trying to get for this sample? It would make the question much clearer

Answer (score 4):

If you need the max you can use the proper aggregation function

```
  select max(score), level 
  from table 
  group by level
  order by level asc
```

for the id

then

```
select * from table 
where (score, level) in (select max(score), level 
                         from table 
                        group by level) 

order by level
```

Comment: OP, from what I gather, wants the `id` associated to that level/max(score) combo.

Comment: @JNevill  . i have updated the answer with the  select * for getting the id too

Comment: I didn't know you could do that `WHERE (score, level) in (SELECT)`.. That's pretty handy!